# php connection pooling mysql

Tags: php, mysql, connection, connection-pooling

I am planning to use MYSQL. Is there a connection pooling extension available? Or what is the normal practice for connection? 
Is this the one used in every where...

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "test");
```

Do people use just normal `mysql_connect` or `pconnect`..? How better is `pconnect` and what setting should I do for PConnect?

Answer (score 24):

have you ever used `mysql_pconnect()` ?
`mysql_pconnect()` acts very much like `mysql_connect()` with two major differences.

First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (`mysql_close()` will not close links established by `mysql_pconnect()`).

This type of link is therefore called 'persistent'

Check it [here](http://ir.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect)

Answer (score 10):

> Persistent connection support was
>   introduced in PHP 5.3 for the mysqli
>   extension. Support was already present
>   in PDO MYSQL and ext/mysql. The idea
>   behind persistent connections is that
>   a connection between a client process
>   and a database can be reused by a
>   client process, rather than being
>   created and destroyed multiple times.
>   This reduces the overhead of creating
>   fresh connections every time one is
>   required, as unused connections are
>   cached and ready to be reused.
>
> Unlike the mysql extension, mysqli
>   does not provide a separate function
>   for opening persistent connections. **To
>   open a persistent connection you must
>   prepend p: to the hostname when
>   connecting.**

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

```
sample code:
$GLOBALS["mysqli"] = new mysqli('p:localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');
```

edit: Sorry for the dupe, didn't see the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

use the mysqli or the PDO extension instead of the old mysql extension.

you can tell the `mysqli_connect` or `mysqli::__construct` to use persistent connection, if you prefix your hostname with 'p:'

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3, mysqli supports persistent connections, you just need to prepend p: to the front of the host name.

If you are running Apache, have you tried looking into connection pooling with mysql through the Apache mod_dbd module? It supports connection pooling for MySQL. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dbd.html

Comment: Thanks for noting the 'p:' host prefix for persistent connections requires **PHP version 5.3**.  Haven't found that little nugget anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 connection functions:

**mysql_connect**: normal connection, no pooling, you cannot execute stored procedures (just sql)

**mysql_pconnect**: pooled connection, you cannot execute stored procedures (just sql)

**mysqli_connect**: normal connection, no pooling, you can execute stored procedures (needs mysql 5 or higher)

**mysqli_pconnect**: DOES NOT EXIST. There is no built in connection function both handling stored procedures and pooling

My advice (via experience and surfing):

If you need stored procedures, omit pooling and use mysqli_connect

If you do not need stored procedures, use mysql_pconnect

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is absolutely possible in PHP - however you should use **swoole** or **openswoole** extension that brings along a lot of async/parallelization features:
https://openswoole.com/docs/get-started/installation

After that you can use normal **mysqli** or **pdo** php extensions to set up connection pools.

See these examples:
https://github.com/open-smf/connection-pool
https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/connection-pool

Some frameworks already handle that for you:
https://hyperf.wiki/2.2/#/en/pool

edit: i use smf connection pool with mezzio micro-framework and openswoole and its rock solid for mysql and redis.