# Should I pass my $mysqli variable to each function?

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, mysqli

I am having a little problem passing from mysql_* to mysqli object oriented.

My **index.php** file is structured like including two files:

```
include('connect.php');
include('function.php');
```

The connect.php file contains:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "test", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

In the **function.php** file there is a function called ***showPage*** that takes no arguments but uses the **$mysqli** connection, in lines like...

```
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ID DESC"); // Seleziono tutto il contenuto della tabella
```

I cannot manage it to work **without passing to the function the $mysqli variable**, but this was not necessary when I used mysql_* deprecated functions!

Can I understand why, and what's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: @Wired once you've removed your password, then probablu you still use it

Comment: As said before it was of an old database (in local too), I am testing on it. But still I don't want my data to be written all around the web =P it bothers me anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User-defined functions have their own variable scope in PHP. You need to pass `$mysqli` to the function as a parameter, or start the function with `global $mysqli`.

This exact problem is given as an example on the [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) page:

> However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is
>   introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default
>   limited to the local function scope. **For example, this script will not
>   produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local
>   version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value
>   within this scope.** You may notice that this is a little bit different
>   from the C language in that global variables in C are automatically
>   available to functions unless specifically overridden by a local
>   definition. This can cause some problems in that people may
>   inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global variables must
>   be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in
>   that function.

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

Comment: Global variables are evil xD but your was the best answer. I was used to C that's why I couldn't get that. I prefer passing the variables as parameter everytime at this point. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, a global variable is imo a perfectly valid and understandable design pattern.  After all, the database connection object IS a global object in your application.  However, I would wrap your mysqli object in a user created object of your own, and use this object globally, as this will give you the flexibility to make improvements/upgrades as necessary without having to make wholesale changes to your app.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot manage it to work **without passing to the function the $mysqli variable**, but this was not necessary when I used mysql_* deprecated functions!

That is not really correct. Even in the old `mysql_*` function you actually had to pass the link identifier if you needed to specify to *which* database connection you were relating to, e.g.:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

Also what this example shows, you had to pass along the `$result`, too. In case you did left out the `$link` parameter:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The mysql extension did look internally for the last used connection. If none would have been found, it would have created a new one with the parameters set in php.ini. That just for your information to better understood why and how this worked in the past.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use connection pooling, it's worth to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830707/php-connection-pooling-mysql) out.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('p:localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name');
```