# mysqli_query errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I define my `$link` in `database.php`:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oop");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

After that i include this in my `header.php`:

```
include "../includes/database.php";
```

Then i use it in the `mysqli_query` calls:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Menu") 
          or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div id= menulist>';
    echo '<div class="menu" id="menu-'.$row['menu_id'].'">';
    echo $row['menu_name'] . " - ". $row['menu_weight']
         . "<a class='delete' href='?delete=".$row['menu_id']
         ."'><img src='images/delete.png' /></a>";
    echo '</div>';
```

The following error occurs:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/oop/admin/menu_class.php on line 39

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I pass my $mysqli variable to each function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016462/should-i-pass-my-mysqli-variable-to-each-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with mysqli. It's [Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. Use `global` keyword to make $link available. And it's obviously a duplicate question of many