# autocomplete function using jquery how to fasten timer

Tags: php, autocomplete

I tried to apply autocomplete option retrieving data from database. The reference link used - http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-php-mysql-json-example.html

It worked well, 
but the question I have is:

The data gets popped up after a slight delay of 2 seconds, How can I increase the timer such that it gets displayed (almost) instantly?

Thanks in advance!
Samuel Mathews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting data slower than you expect. You are limited by the speed at which your database returns the results. I can suggest you following to speed up.

**Front End:**
jQuery autocomplete has a default [delay](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay) of 300 miliseconds between keystroke and service call You might want to reduce that.

**Back end**
1. Dont make a new connection to mysql from php for every request. Enable database connection pooling. It improves performance quite a lot. I dont know how to do connection pool in php. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830707/php-connection-pooling-mysql) might help.

2. If possible cache the results in php, so that you dont hit the db everytime.
3. Use an external service to serve data for autocomplete. Look at [Autocomplete as a Service](http://aaas.io). This relieves you writing backend for autocomplete, produces faster results.

Answer (score 1):

probably the response to your question is about speeding up your query or whatever you do in the server side,if is against a database try to use indexes and well known optimizing tips. check this link  for more tips.
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-sql-tips-to-speed-up-your-database`