# Auto complete movie names

Tags: php, mysql, lucene

I have the Jquery auto complete currently implemented for searching movie names.  I have it starting a 2 characters with a 150ms delay in between.

I have a PHP and Mysql DB behind it that does a like '%term%' search to return the results.

I find this is pretty slow and database intensive.

I tried using Mysql's full text search, but didn't have much luck - perhaps I wasn't using the right match type.

Can someone suggest tweaks to the mysql full text or whether I should go straight to an indexing solution like Lucene or Sphinx and if they work well on partial matches with only 1-3 characters?

Answer (score 0):

You are limited by the speed at which your database returns the results. I can suggest you following to speed up.

1. Dont make a new connection to mysql from php for every request. Enable database connection pooling. It improves performance quite a lot. I dont know how to do connection pool in php. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830707/php-connection-pooling-mysql) might help.
2. If possible cache the results in php, so that you dont hit the database everytime.
3. Use an external service to serve data for autocomplete. Look at [Autocomplete as a Service](http://aaas.io/). This relieves you writing backend for autocomplete, produces faster results.