# Optimize MySqli request

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website that works like a console. I have a status script that check if the page is offline or you're blacklisted/whitelisted. I do this by look up the IP in my database. Then after that I use a switch to direct the user. I use javaScript to redirect because the site uses ajax and I can't get header('Location: xxx'); to work with it(A problem for another time).

When I run the site with the status page it loads twice as slow, and it doesn't help that page loads this script each time the user uses a command.

Do you have any suggestions on how to optimize it to load faster? I´m open for all ideas. Thanks for your time.

```php
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
};

$conn = new MySQLi('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

$statusRank = "";

$sql = "SELECT enable FROM global WHERE enable = '1' AND setting = 'frontend'";
$query  = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    $statusRank = "offline";
}

$sql = "SELECT ip FROM blacklist WHERE ip = '$ip'";
$query  = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    $statusRank = "blacklist";
}

$sql = "SELECT ip FROM whitelist WHERE ip = '$ip'";
$query  = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    $statusRank = "whitelist";
}

switch ($statusRank) {
    case "blacklist":
        ?><script>window.location.replace("include/blacklist.php");</script><?php
    break;
    case "whitelist":
    break;
    case "offline":
        ?><script>window.location.replace("include/offline.php");</script><?php
    break;
    default:
};
```

Comment: which one is the query that loads slow? "Twice as slow" is no value you can work with.. is it a millisecond? Minute? Hour? And without your table structure / indexes there is no chance to help you.

Comment: Sorry... I goes from being as close to instant as it gets maybe around 300-500 millisecond and when the script is enabled +/- 2 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas starting with the easiest to implement :

- Make sure you have an index on the `ip` column in the `blacklist` and `whitelist` tables.
- I am not very familiar with this in PHP but you should probably use a persistent connection.  Opening a database connection is an expensive operation.  See [php connection pooling mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830707/php-connection-pooling-mysql) for more details.
- Finally you could merge the three queries together and instead of counting the rows just check if the ip is found or not.  Something like :

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM global WHERE enable = '1' AND setting = 'frontend') THEN 'T' ELSE  'F' 
  END AS offline,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE ip = '$ip') THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
  END AS blacklisted,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM whitelist WHERE ip = '$ip') THEN 'T' ELSE 'F'
  END AS whilelisted
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the DB once for the IP, start a PHP session, and save the results to it. So on the 2nd and subsequent loads you read from the session.

I would make your select as:

```
SELECT 'blacklisted' FROM blacklist WHERE ip = '$ip' JOIN
SELECT 'whitelisted' FROM whitelist WHERE ip = '$ip'
```

Then you simply have to check each row for strings 'blacklisted' or 'whitelisted' (or b/w for shorter).